# Hourly average for timestamps columns - FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to get the hourly average of two columns. The type of the columns is timestamp.

I try this:

```
select trunc(endtime, 'HH') as Date,
    avg(extract(second from intrvl)
        + extract(minute from intrvl) * 60
        + extract(hour from intrvl) * 60 * 60
        + extract(day from intrvl) * 60 * 60 * 24) as average
from (
    select (endtime - starttime) intrvl 
    from mytable
)
group by Date;
```

I do not know if this is the right way to go at all. But the query is not correct. I get this error: `00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"`

In the end I would like to get a table like this one:

```
Date average
16/11/2021 08:00 5.786
16/11/2021 09:00 8.996
```

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all the columns you are going to use in the outer-query in the `SELECT` clause of the inner-query and you cannot use an alias of the `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause in the same sub-query:

```sql
select trunc(endtime, 'HH') as "Date",
       avg(
           extract(second from intrvl)
         + extract(minute from intrvl) * 60
         + extract(hour   from intrvl) * 60 * 60
         + extract(day    from intrvl) * 60 * 60 * 24
       ) as average
from (
  select endtime,
         endtime - starttime AS intrvl 
  from   mytable
)
group by trunc(endtime, 'HH');
```

---

If you do not have (or are not worried about) fractional seconds then you could also use:

```sql
select trunc(endtime, 'HH') as "Date",
       AVG(
         (CAST(endtime AS DATE) - CAST(starttime AS DATE))
         * 60 * 60 * 24
       ) AS average
from   mytable
group by trunc(endtime, 'HH');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbc2cd908a2def60081f4ce3a48da52e)*

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is reserved word (for a datatype), you can't use it as an alias unless you enclose it into double quotes as

```
  SELECT TRUNC (endtime, 'HH') AS "Date",
         AVG (
              EXTRACT (SECOND FROM intrvl)
            + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM intrvl) * 60
            + EXTRACT (HOUR FROM intrvl) * 60 * 60
            + EXTRACT (DAY FROM intrvl) * 60 * 60 * 24) AS average
    FROM (SELECT (endtime - starttime) intrvl FROM mytable)
GROUP BY "Date";
```

Alternatively, rename it to e.g. `c_date`

```
SELECT TRUNC (endtime, 'HH') AS c_date,
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get: `00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`..

Comment: That's because you're referencing a column that doesn't exist, I presume. That might be ENDTIME (in TRUNC(ENDTIME)) because it doesn't exist in a subquery.

Comment: Yes, now I got it :-) Thanks a lot!